# How do i create UWP project with dotnet command

Tags: .net, uwp

i want to build a uwp app using the dotnet command but i cannot find it in the documentation
is there any way to create a custom template or using an existing one.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, there isn't any `dotnet new` to achieve this at the moment.

Depending on your goals, you could use alternate solutions.

- In a script, you could run `dotnet new` using another template and modify the resulting files to match a UWP projet.
- You could create your own `dotnet new` template by yourself by using the resulting files that you get when creating a UWP project via Visual Studio.